# HBase row write fails due to NoColumnFamily though I have added it

Tags: hadoop, hbase

This may be a standard asynchronous operation issue. Adding Column Family through [HBaseAdmin.addColumnFamily](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#addColumnFamily%28org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName,%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor%29) is asynchronous. Now I need to add rows after adding this columnFamily and this is throwing me error of NoColumnFamily. How can I defer adding rows till columnFamily is added other than just checking if columnFamily exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a column family. You will need to: 
 1. Disable Table
 2. Add column Family
 3. Enable Table.
 Then only you will be able to write data to that column family. After following above 3 steps there is no uncertainty about existence of that column family.

Comment: Thanks, I also did the same as given here, https://github.com/bakash/Kundera/blob/trunk/kundera-hbase/src/main/java/com/impetus/client/hbase/admin/HBaseDataHandler.java#L154